# Why the environment variable is not working with Docker run command used in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, aws-ssm

Below is my Deployment stage pipeline code.

```
 stage('Deploy') {
        if (continueBuild) {
            println("Start Deployment");
            //Deploy step for liberty-web
            if ("${repo_name}" == 'enterprise-content-management/liberty-web') {
                if ("${deploy_env}" == "DEV") {
                    def REACT_APP_CONFIGS = sh(script: "aws ssm get-parameter --region us-east-1 --name \"/liberty/config/liberty-web_dev/app.config\" | jq -r '.Parameter.Value'", returnStdout: true).trim().replaceAll('\n', '').replaceAll('\"', '\\\\"');

                    def APP_SPECIFIC_CONFIG = sh(script: "aws ssm get-parameter --region us-east-1 --name \"/liberty/config/liberty-web_dev/app.appSpecificConfig\" | jq -r '.Parameter.Value'", returnStdout: true).trim().replaceAll('\n', '').replaceAll('\"', '\\\\"');

                    print REACT_APP_CONFIGS
                    print APP_SPECIFIC_CONFIG

                    def CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID = sh(script: "aws ssm get-parameter --region us-east-1 --name \"/liberty/config/liberty-web_dev/cloudfront.distribution.id\" | jq -r '.Parameter.Value'", returnStdout: true).trim()
                    print CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID

                    def DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET = sh(script: "aws ssm get-parameter --region us-east-1 --name \"/liberty/config/liberty-web_dev/s3.bucket.name\" | jq -r '.Parameter.Value'", returnStdout: true).trim()
                    print DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET

                    writeFile file: 'build-web-dev.sh', text: "#!/usr/bin/env bash \n docker run --rm  --env REACT_APP_CONFIGS=\"${REACT_APP_CONFIGS}\" --env APP_SPECIFIC_CONFIG=\"${APP_SPECIFIC_CONFIG}\" --name liberty-web -v /data/jenkins/workspace/liberty-web-deployment:/Project -w /Project  node:12-alpine npm run build"
                    sh 'cat build-web-dev.sh'
                    sh 'bash build-web-dev.sh'
                    sh "aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID} --paths \"/*\" && aws s3 sync build/ s3://${DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET}"
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

This is a node app. When i try to access below 2 env variables mentioned(REACT_APP_CONFIGS, APP_SPECIFIC_CONFIG) only REACT_APP_CONFIGS works. These values of the params are stored in SSM in AWS. I tried by putting the same value for both variables. But still the same. Ex;-

```
In my node app
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_CONFIGS)  -> gives correct value
console.log(process.env.APP_SPECIFIC_CONFIG)  -> undefined
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: what is the return value from your sh script for APP_SPECIFIC_CONFIG?

Comment: it is undefined

Comment: I mean the output when you run the sh script. It will return something, even your script cannot work.